# Redirecting Japanese Characters

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, search

I am attempting to redirect the search term of a wordpress site to a non wordpress site. I have managed to do this fine for English characters by adding the following to my `.htaccess` file and using the redirection plugin with regex enabled;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [R,L]
```

Search term *"wallet"* gets redirected to: `http://jpdev.globe-trotter.com/search/wallet`

Using the redirection plugin I have redirected `/search/` with regex enabled to the following url: `vulcanize.jp/products/list?name={searchterm}` which again works fine for English Characters.

My issue is this is a Japanese website and when I search for a Japanese term `{ウォレット}` it redirects as;

`%25E3%2582%25A6%25E3%2582%25A9%25E3%2583%25AC%25E3%2583%2583%25E3%2583%2588`
instead of `ウォレット` and causes an error.

Is there a way of redirecting the search term to `https://vulcanize.jp/products/list?name=` without encoding the Japanese characters?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem in future, this is how I solved it.

The issue with the encoding Japanese characters was to do with the htaccess redirect. After removing the lines from the htaccess file I used the following within my functions.php;

```html
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
 if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
  wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
  exit();
 } 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

This effectively performed the same action as the htaccess file was trying to do but doing it this way does not encode the Japanese characters. From there the Redirection plugin could redirect /search/ with regex enabled to the destination url with the Japanese characters added to the end as needed.

Got there in the end.